# Where is my database in android phone?

Tags: android, eclipse

I have created a database like this:

```
db = openOrCreateDatabase("ImisData.db3",SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null);
```

After installing and running application in real phone, where do I find my database? I looked in to data folder but I didn't even find my package name there.

Any help please??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its in your internal memory's `/data/data/package_name/databases` folder. In order to get access to that folder, i believe your phone must be *rooted* and need to use some kind of *root explorer*.

Comment: really? My phone is not rooted and I have full access to it via DDMS in eclipse.

Comment: are you sure its full access? because i doubt that :)

Comment: well I can access my databases no problem at all, same as I would with the emulator.  Using a samsung galaxy s3.  I can download the database as I would with the emulator and then open them with sqlite explorer.

Comment: Hey @Waqas thanks your answer helped. I wasn't able to see my db there so just changed the path of the db.

Comment: BTW @Jon you can see it in DDMS but can't see in real phone. That's what I experienced.

Comment: @hirensoni I haven't done much database stuff in Android, however I am 99% certain that I can access my database on my s3 not just in the emulator.  I may have this wrong and may have been doing something else at the time, however I am almost certain.  I will, however, to clear things up, check later this evening.

Comment: @JonTaylor: You might be accessing `mnt/sdcard/Android/data/` folder. It is not in your internal memory. Its pointing to sd-card. Anyhow, at least I can't access my phones' **data** folder from internal memory in DDMS.

Comment: I don't have an sd card in my phone :) haha, to be honest its probably a mistake on my part.

Answer (score 0):

It should be in `/data/data/your.package/databases`

You'll need a rooted phone to access this. You will need this command to retrieve your database:

```
adb pull <remote> <local>
```

Comment: @JonTaylor iuf your phone isn't rooted, you don't have access to /data

Comment: My phone says differently, as I explained in a comment below one of the other answers, I have a galaxy s3 and can access the data folder no problem at all just like I would on the emulator.  And my phone deffinately is not rooted.

Answer (score 0):

internal memory

/data/data/your_apk_package_name/databases/

Answer (score 0):

using this method it will be created in ("/data/data/YourPackageName/databases/")..